# CRIU - checkpointing a TCP socket without stopping it (COW ?)

Tags: sockets, tcp, failover, copy-on-write

I'm working on a failover mechanism for TCP connections. If a host breaks down (hardware failure), I'd like to be able to take up the connection on another machine. I want to stream periodically the state of the "live" socket to a "backup" host and have it take-over (tcp_repair and all) when the "live" host breaks.

I have a prototype with libsoccr and it works OK, except that I have to pause the socket for some time, and depending on the buffer sizes it can take some time (hundreds of microsecs, sometimes 1-2ms) and it's a bit problematic for my application, since I dump its state quite often (~every 10ms).

I'd like to be able to checkpoint a TCP socket (via libsoccr if it's the way, I'm also OK with raw syscalls if necessary) *without* pausing the socket. Is it possible to just "fork" or duplicate a TCP socket with its complete state, with some kind of CoW  so that the live socket isn't paused ?

Would fork help here ?
Any idea ?

Comment: Route the packets via backup host. and make backup host keep track of current state.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I'm not sure I understand. Are you proposing that the backup host be the one establishing the TCP connection and copies (via netfilter/other) all ingress/egress traffic to the 'online' host and keeps tab on the connection state? Or maybe copy all the i/o traffic from the 'online' to the 'backup' one. Anyway, two things seem problematic here, any way I look at it: 1) if the backup host fails I lose the complete connection state, when it comes back it can't pick up. There's gonna be some missing info. Next sequence number for example? And 2) lots of ways to mess it up

Comment: I'm thinking what you're proposing is done in some high-availability firewall boxes. But I still don't see how to handle the 'handover' in all cases, all states of a TCP socket. Would it help to also transmit some additional info that conntrack has? Can conntrack changes/updates be streamed / dumped? Through netlink maybe? Is there a COTS/OSS solution there?